# Binary Search Tree fail to insert

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-search-tree

It works well when only insert value to the root. But when it comes to inserting other node, it fails to insert and the only thing i get is the root value. Here is the code:

```
class BinarySearchTree():
class BinarySearchTreeNode():
    def __init__(self,leftchildnode,rightchildnode,item):
        self.leftchildnode = leftchildnode
        self.rightchildnode = rightchildnode
        self.item = item

def __init__(self):
    self.root = None

def insert(self,item):
    if self.root == None:
        self.cur = self.BinarySearchTreeNode(None,None,item)
        self.root = self.cur
    else:
        self.recursiveinsert(self.root,item)

def recursiveinsert(self,node,item):
    if node is None:
        node = self.BinarySearchTreeNode(None,None,item)
    else:
        if item < node.item:
            self.recursiveinsert(node.leftchildnode,item)
        else:
            self.recursiveinsert(node.rightchildnode,item)

def inorderdisplay(self):
    self.recursive_inorder_display(self.root)
    
def recursive_inorder_display(self,BinarySearchTreeNode):
    if BinarySearchTreeNode != None:
        self.recursive_inorder_display(BinarySearchTreeNode.leftchildnode)
        print(BinarySearchTreeNode.item)
        self.recursive_inorder_display(BinarySearchTreeNode.rightchildnode)

tree = BinarySearchTree()
tree.insert(13)
tree.insert(2)
tree.insert(15)
tree.inorderdisplay()
```

Once i run the inroder the only result i get is 13, could you point out where's the error?

Answer (score 0):

- Your init statement in class BinaryTree should be modified,
- You should pass the left and right elements to do that in recursive manner
  Please try checking this github repo for further details,

```
#This should be changed to
    def __init__(self,leftchildnode,rightchildnode,item):
         self.leftchildnode = leftchildnode
         self.rightchildnode = rightchildnode
         self.item = item

#Please use this for the structure

    def __init__(self, item):
         self.leftchildNode = None
         self.rightchildNode = None
         self.item = item
```

So you can check the github repo below for detailed code

[Please check the github repo here for detailed code](https://github.com/saran-surya/binary-tree-in-python/blob/master/binary%20tree%20addition.py)